# React Router v6 Link component not changing the page at root url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, hyperlink, react-router

I have created a `Link` on a `Post` that links to the `Post Page`. When the link is clicked with the url at `'/'` the link doesn't work correctly, it displays the correct link in the url e.g. `http://localhost:3000/posts/624a771b42211849eaada885` but the page doesn't redirect, the only way it works is if I refresh the page. However, if I am on my `Popular Posts` page the link works correctly. To be clear the Post is in a component called Posts which displays all of the Posts. The Posts component is a shared component across many components, such as Home page (`'/'`) and Popular Posts (`/popular`) the link works in all other pages except for when at `'/'`

Below is the `Link`.

```
<Link to={`/posts/${_id}`}>
  <h2 className='post-title'>{title}</h2>
</Link>
```

My routes are set up with the following:

```
<Route element={!token ? <Navigate replace to='/login' /> : <Navbar />}>
  <Route
    path='/'
    element={<Home />}
  >
    <Route
      path='/popular'
      element={<Popular />}
    />
    <Route 
      path='/posts/:postId' 
      element={<PostPage />} 
    />
  </ Route>
</Route>
```

In my Navbar I have:

```
const Navbar = () => {

  return(
    <>
      <nav>
      </nav>
      <Outlet />
    </>
  )
}
```

and finally, in my Home.js I have this:

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>content</div>
    <div>content</div>
    <div className='home-posts-container'>
          {window.location.pathname === '/' ? <PopularPosts /> : 
           <Outlet />}
    </div>
    <div>content</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Are `Navbar` and `Home` components rendering `Outlet` components for the nested routes to be rendered into? `{window.location.pathname === '/' ? <PopularPosts /> : <Outlet />}` doesn't seem like something you want to be doing. Can you post more complete and reproducible code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: edited above, sorry for incomplete code, thought I added what was needed. Didn't realize the context could be the issue. Thanks @DrewReese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell of your `Home` component with

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>content</div>
      <div>content</div>
      <div className="home-posts-container">
        {window.location.pathname === "/" ? <PopularPosts /> : <Outlet />}
      </div>
      <div>content</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

You want to render the `PopularPosts` component *exactly* when the path is `"/"`, otherwise you want to render one of the matched nested routes.

The issue is that with the above implementation the `Outlet` isn't rendered when the path changes so none of the nested routes are matchable.

It appears you want the `Home` component to be a layout route, it should render all the `div` elements and content, ***and just*** the `Outlet`. Move the `PopularPosts` component into an index route.

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>content</div>
      <div>content</div>
      <div className="home-posts-container">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
      <div>content</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route element={!token ? <Navigate replace to="/login" /> : <Navbar />}>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />}>
      <Route index element={<PopularPosts />} />
      <Route path="/popular" element={<Popular />} />
      <Route path="/posts/:postId" element={<PostPage />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-link-component-not-changing-the-page-at-root-url]

For more information see:

- [Layout routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes)
- [Index routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#index-routes)